# Accessing child methods in parent for mongoose succeeds in array and fails with single child

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate, instance-methods

**UPDATE : Solution is at bottom of question**

I have an express site using mongoose.

I'll greatly simplify to say that I have adults, kids, and house models. When I create methods on kids, I can call them from within methods on adults and get a result. I can also call them from my .ejs views. However, when I create methods on house, I can only get a result from my .ejs views and get undefined when called from within methods on adults.  Example code follows.

**adult.js**

```
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const adultSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    size: {type: String},
    kids: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Kid', required: true}]
    house:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'House', required: true}
});

adultSchema.method({
  getKidsDescription: function() {
     if (this.kids.length < 1) {
     return 'No kids yet';
   } else {
     let ev = 'Kids, aged: ';
     let kds = this.kids;
     kds.forEach(function(k){
        ev = ev + 'k.getAge()' // works
     })
     return ev;
   }
 },
 getHouseDescription: function(){
    return 'A fabulous house on '+this.house.getFullStreet(); // does not work
 }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Adult', adultSchema);
```

**kid.js**

```
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const kidSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    size: {type: String},
    birthdate: {type:Date}
});

kidSchema.method({
  getAge: function() {
     return (Math.floor(new Date() - this.birthdate)/(1000*60*60*24*365))
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Kid', kidSchema);
```

**house.js**

```
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const houseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    city: {type: String},
    street: {type:String}
});

houseSchema.method({
  getFullStreet: function() {
     return this.street + ' Road';
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('House', houseSchema);
```

When I make a query for theAdult, it looks like this:

**controller.js**

```
exports.main = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.theAdult) {
    try {
      const found = await db.fetchAdult(req.theAdult._id)
      res.render('/main', {
          //theHouse: found.house    //below I show this working
      });
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e.message)
    }
  } else {
      res.redirect('/');
  }
}
```

**db.js**

```
exports.fetchAdult = (id) => {
  return Adult.findById(id)
      .populate({ path: 'kids'})
      .populate({ path: 'house'})
      .exec()
      .then(doc => {
          return doc;
  });
}
```

Assuming house is passed to view as an object when rendered (commented out above), this works

**view.ejs**

```
   <p> <%= theHouse.getFullStreet() %></p>
```

Assuming house populated on the call to load the Adult, this returns undefined.

**view.ejs**

```
   <p> <%= theAdult.house.getFullStreet() %></p>
```

At the same time, both of these work

**view.ejs**

```
   <ul> <% theAdult.kids.forEach(function(k) { %>
          <li><%= k.getAge() %> </li>
        <% }); %>
   </ul>

   <p> <% theAdult.getKidsDescription() %> </p>
```

What I am not understanding is how the method calls work for objects in array and work in the view but do not work for objects on in an array. This is a single child error (for me). If it did not work in the view, I would assume that the method `getFullStreet()` was the problem, but it works in the view. If the array methods could not be called within the parent, I would assume the issue was with trying to access `getFullStreet()` in the parent.

What am I missing?

**SOLUTION**
I was fetching `theAdult` in my call to show view.ejs, but I was then actually relying on `currentAdult` which referred to `req.adult` and did not have the fields populated. My solution was to add a pre hook to the adult schema that always populates house on find.

*in adult.js*

```
adultSchema.pre('find', function() {
  this.populate('house')
})
```

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet describing how the documents are being created, what they look like in the database and how you query for them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing a hydrated theAdult? It might only see the ObjectID, without any other data or methods.

Comment: After looking at this many times, I realized that I was going and fetching `theAdult`, but I was actually using a reference to `req.adult` and that was my problem. I fixed it by adding a pre hook on the mongoose adult schema to always populate house on find. Edit in question above.